# HTML таблица. Не все границы прорисованны

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Буду благодарен.

Мне бы очень помогло если сформировать HTML-таблицу следующего вида (используя простые тэги):

```
+--------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
|                    |          row0           |      row0        |
| row0 (row span=3)  |          row1           |      row1        |
|                    |          row2           |      row2        |
+--------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
|                    |          row3           |      row3        |
| row3 (row span=3)  |          row4           |      row4        |
|                    |          row5           |      row5        |
+--------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
```

То есть в этой таблице 6 строк, но не все границы прорисованы.

**EDIT:** *с учетом комментариев, используя CSS, только в данном случае критично, чтобы стиль добавлялся не наверху документа, а внутри < Table >*

Спасибо

Comment: Эту задачу нельзя решить без CSS.

Comment: Спасибо! А можно CSS добавить внутри определения <Table>, а не где-то там наверху документа? Если так то какую тему CSS посмотреть?

Comment: Добавил полноценный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эту задачу нельзя решить с использованием только HTML. Вам точно придется использовать CSS в том или ином виде.

За сокрытие границ отвечают следующие правила:

```
border-top: none;
border-bottom: none;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
border: none;
```

Вам следует определить несколько стилей для ячеек без границ в одном из подключаемых CSS файлов, либо в теге `<style>`. Это может выглядеть как-то так:

```
td.without-top-border: {
    border-top: none;
}

td.without-bottom-border: {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Кроме того, вы можете скрывать границы с использованием атрибута `style` у элемента `td`, например так:

```
<td style="border-top: none;"></td>
```

Хотя я бы не рекомендовал этот подход из-за смешивания разметки и стилей и возможных проблем с переопределением стилей в будущем.

Comment: Спасибо! Выручили.